# Asp.Net Core Anonymous and Windows Authentication not working together

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get Asp.net core Web API 2.1 working with IIS when both Windows and Anonymous authentications are set to enabled. The API is working great when I turn off anonymous but not when they are both set.

- I have used the authorize attribute and set it at the class level on all my controllers.
- I have set the              services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
- I have enabled both Windows and Anonymous on IIS.

  ```
          _logger.LogInformation("Entered into windows Authentication");
          services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
          services.AddMvcCore(opts =>
          {
          }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
          .AddFormatterMappings()
          .AddDataAnnotations() // Optional if no validation using attributes
          .AddCors()            // 
          .AddApiExplorer()     // Not Optional
          .AddJsonOptions(options =>
          {
              options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
          })
          .AddJsonFormatters(o =>
          {
              o.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
              o.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
          });
  ```

In my startup.cs the Configure method looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Ctrac API");
        });
    }
```

and on my controllers:

```
    [HttpGet, AutoQueryable]
    [Authorize]
    public IQueryable<DocumentViewModel> Get([FromServices] IQueryableRepository repository, [FromServices] IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {

       _logger.LogInformation($"This is httpContext userid: {context?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name}"); //This is null
        return repository.GetIQueryable<DocumentView>().Where(x => x.ActiveFlag == "Y"
        && _userRepo.User.DocTypes.Contains(x.DocumentTypeCode))
        .OrderBy(a => a.DocTypeCategory).ThenBy(a => a.SubCategory).ThenByDescending(a => a.Id).UseAsDataSource(_mapper).For<DocumentViewModel>();

    }
```

context?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name I'm expecting this to yield something because the method has the Authorize Annotation in it.

Comment: Anonymous supersedes any other authentication methods on IIS, so yes the two are by design not working with each other.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Fail to reproduce your issue with [TestWindowsAuth](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3h0UfwJqfMKBFBgHh)

Comment: @Tom Did you get any solution as I am facing the same.

Comment: Maybe put [AllowAnonymous] on the methods that should be publicly available?